# How can i split strings that has prefix and suffix in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, split

I have string that is stored in a variable in this form :

```
var c = "<p>Let's try with single inputs : *[]*</p>"
```

I can easily split and convert the `*[]*` into `<span>` using this method **[a]**:

```
var res = c.split("*[]*");
if(res.length > 1){
  var strContent = res[0];
  var inptSoal = ' <span id="content-input" class="al question mb-0">[ &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ]</span> ';
  strContent += inptSoal;
  strContent += res[1];

  c = strContent;
} return c;
```

But now, let's say that i have this form of string **[b]** :

```
var c = "<p>Let's try with 2 inputs : *[Input 1]* and *[Input 2]*</p>"
```

How can i split (and convert) every `*[` and `]*` (that has strings inside of it) into HTML `<span>` element? Thanks in advance

---

## **EDIT**

To make it clearer, using the *method* i write above (**[a]**) it will return this in my website :
[image]

What i want to do is to return the same result if the condition is like the second form (**[b]**) i mentioned above. How can i achieve this?

---

## **SOLVED** ✅

Every answers here solved my problem. The first answer here was [Ofek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11885241/ofek)'s answer. It works well, what i need to do to achieve the result i want is only to change the `"<span>" + input + "</span>"` inside the `replace()` function into :

`"<span id='content-input' class='al question mb-0'>" + input + "</span>"` to make the `span` element has the CSS Style like my screenshot above.

Other two answers, [sid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8138192/sid)'s answer and [Rahul Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5251507/rahul-kumar)'s answer also works well. But i prefer to choose [Rahul Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5251507/rahul-kumar)'s answer for its simplicity.

Thanks in advance to everyone that answered my questions!

Comment: Could you complete the question with some examples of inputs with expected conversion results? It isn't clear if substrings between `*[` and `]*` have to be surrounded by `<span>` and `</span>` or just replaced. Are nested brackets possible: `*[str1*[str2]*str3]*`?

Comment: @AleksandrBaklanov Hi thanks for commenting, i've updated my question. Would you mind to check it out again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `regex` to match the pattern and pass it to `String.replace()` method to replace the matched pattern in your string with new string `<span>$1</span>`. Here `$1` indicates the captured group which is a content inside brackets `*[...]*`.

```js
str = "<p>Let's try with 2 inputs : *[Input 1]* and *[Input 2]*</p>"
const regex = /\*\[(.*?)\]\*/g;
const finalStr = str.replace(regex, "<span>$1</span>");
console.log(finalStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```
function replaceWithInput(str, replacer) {
  var arr = str.split("*[");
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var index = arr[i].indexOf("]*");
    arr[i] = replacer(arr[i].slice(0, index)) + arr[i].slice(index + 2);
  }
  return arr.join("");
}
```

you use it like so:

```
function replace(input) {
  return "<span>" + input + "</span>"
}
replaceWithInput("<p>Let's try with 2 inputs : *[Input 1]* and *[Input 2]*</p>", replace);
```

Comment: Hi it works great, it replace every *[ with <span> and ]* with </span>, unfortunately this is not what i want to achieve, pardon my mistake. Would you mind to check out my question again? I've updated my question

Comment: you can change the method replace to whatever you want.
but i see peoples posted about regex, i didn't knew you can use regex with argument, and its better than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex you could do,

```
let c = "<p>Let's try with 2 inputs : *[Input 1]* and *[Input 2]*</p>";

let newC = c.replace(/\*([[])/g, '<span>');
let newC2 = newC.replace(/\]([*])/g, '</span>');

console.log(newC2);
```